# How to implement ajax based toast notification for add to cart, wishlist and compare?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, wishlist, compare, ajaxaddtocart

Is there any way to show toaster notification using  jQuery for **add to cart** and **wishlist** and **compare** from product list page and detail page.

Want to show some of the below toast notification after add to cart event and wishlist and compare.
https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Bootstrap-Based-Toast-Notification-Plugin-toaster.html
https://colorlib.com/wp/jquery-notification-plugins/

For ajax based functionality - i'm using below free extensionn.

https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/ajax-suite-magento-2/

Answer (score 2):

You can go with this extension. Not used it personally but demo seems promising.

[Extension  Link](https://simbeez.com/shop/toast-notification-extension-for-magento2.html)